Rigging armature and parts
I am trying to make an animation with a custom skeleton.
I initially have a model sculpted in 3 different parts. I joined all the parts, cleaned them up, and added the bones. Then I did an automatic weights to bind the mesh to the bones.
But a few parts don't react the right way to the animation.
The first picture is the initial pose. Every piece is in the right place.

The second picture: when I open the upper bone, two of the teeth don't stay in place:

The weights are correct, so I don't know how to correct this.
If you could point to me to the right direction, it would be really helpful.
The result, after implementing the solution by moonboots:


For teeth, as you don't want any deformation of these objects, and they should only be part of one vertex group, instead of parent With Automatic Weights, you should better parent With Empty Groups, for the moment the mesh has as many vertex groups as you have bones but no vertex has been assigned to any ofthese groups, then select the teeth and assign them to the group they should be part of:

As you can see, the vertices of your teeth are part of 2 different vertex groups, Tongue02 and UpperJaw, they should be only part of UpperJaw:

You need to select them all and remove them from Tongue02:

Or select all the upper part, remove from all group, then assign to UpperJaw:


Ok, I just tried that. But I don't really know what to do next tho
When I go to Pose Mode after putting all the vertices to vertex groups, and try to manipulate, nothing happens....
I feel like I am missing one step....

Please share your file

Here is the file....
https://we.tl/t-kCHUVV1MSX

I've edited my answer   @lostsf

Ohhhh! Thank you so much! I will try that tomorrow and get back to you! Thank you! I just can't believe that little vertex was making the entire mess... Thank you for spotting it!

It's not this vertex, it's all the teeth vertices, I'm just showing that if you select one of these vertices it shows that it is assigned to 2 vertex groups

yihhhaaaaa! thank you so much! it actually took time make a clean re-grouping. But it works! I am so happy!
thank you thank you thank you!
